# Can't get an int to update outside of the while loop

Tags: c++

When it runs the winnings or losses are taken or added from the bank and then it is run again the bank is set back to a 25$ bank not the updated bank

```
int main()
{
srand(time(0));
int bank = 25;
int total;

char answer;

cout << "Come play Spin the Wheel. The wheel has numbers from 1-10." <<  endl
    << "If you spin an even number you lose that amount. If you spin" << endl
    << "an odd number you win that amount. You start with a 25$ bank." << endl; 
cout << "Your bank is $" << bank << ". Would you like to spin the wheel? (y/n):" << endl;
cin >> answer;

while (toupper(answer) == 'Y')
{
    int num = rand() % 10 + 1;

    if (bank <= 10)
    {
        cout << "Sorry you must have more than 10$ to play" << endl;
    }
else if (num % 2 == 0 )
    {
    total = bank + num;
        cout << "You spun a " << num << " and won $" << num << endl;
        cout << "Your bank is now: $" << total << endl;
    }

    else

    {
        total = bank - num;
        cout << "You spun a " << num << " and lost $" << num << endl;
        cout << "Your bank is now: $" << total << endl;
    }
    cout << "Would you like to play Again (y/n) ?" << endl;
    cin >> answer;
}





return 0;
}
```

When it runs the winnings or losses are taken or added from the bank and then it is run again the bank is set back to a 25$ bank not the updated bank

Comment: Where are you updating Bank?

Comment: it was originally     cout << "Your bank is now: $" << bank+num << endl;   but i tried throwing it into a single variable under total which is also not working

Comment: at the end cout << "Would you like to play Again (y/n) ?" << endl;
  cin >> answer; which runs the while loop again. Sorry im really new and had no other way to run the game again with what ive learned at least

Comment: bank value not set to the new total so you never change it from its original $25. Try bank = total

Comment: how can i set the new total to bank

Comment: Like this bank = total

Comment: My god that was so minor guys im so sorry ive been working on this for two hours and didn't even think of the simplest thing that worked thank you so much Ryan! Do i need to mark this post as answered?

Comment: I'll post my comment as an answer then pls select the check mark to confirm it as correct. Trust me you it's so easy to miss the obvious especially when you been staring at the same code for ages. Get used to that as that's part of programming. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You initialize bank to be 25 dollar in this function. Inside the while loop only total is updated not bank.

Another problem arises when there is too few money to play. I suppose you would like to display your message one time, but you are stuck inside the loop because it is never broken out of.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your else if and else statements are backwards.

```
num % 2 == 0
```

Would signify that the number was even, if true. The instructions say that you lose the money if the number is even.

Bank will never be less than or equal to 10 because you are never setting bank to anything after the initial 25.  Its always 25.

The variable total seems redundant. Maybe add or subtract the amount rolled directly from bank.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set

```
bank = total
```

else you never change its value